# What are the similarities between these 3 limits?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have 3 limits and I'm pretty sure that the process of solving them it's the same.

$L_1=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\cdot \int_{0}^{1}x^{2n}\sin(\frac{x\cdot \pi)}{2})dx$

$L_2=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\cdot \int_{-1}^{0}(x+e^{x})^{n}dx$

$L_3=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\cdot \int_{2}^{e}(\ln(x))^{n}dx$

I solved $L_2$ and $L_3$ like this:I took a $c$ such that $f(x)=x+e^{x}>0$ on $[c,0]$ and I got $n\int_{-1}^{0}f^n=n\int_{-1}^{c}f^n+n\int_{c}^{0}f^n$

Why the first integral has limit $0$?

For the second integral I got $\frac{1}{f'(0)}\leq \frac{1}{f'(x)}\leq \frac{1}{f'(c)}\Rightarrow \frac{n}{f'(0)}\int_{c}^{0}f^n\cdot f'<n\int_{c}^{0}f^n<\frac{n}{f'(c)}\int_{c}^{0}f^n\cdot f'\Rightarrow \\\Rightarrow\frac{n}{f'(0)(n+1)}(f^{n+1}(0)-f^{n+1}(c))<n\int_{c}^{0}f^n< \frac{n}{f'(c)(n+1)}(f^{n+1}(0)-f^{n+1}(c))\Rightarrow \\\Rightarrow \frac{1}{f'(0)}\leq \lim_{n\to\infty }n\int_{c}^{0}f^n\leq \frac{1}{f'(c)}$

So the limit is  $\frac{1}{f'(0)}=\frac{1}{2}$

I followed the same process for $L_3$.How about $L_1$?How to solve it like this ? I mean in the same way.

In my book I got some properties like: $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\cdot \int_{a}^{1}x^{n}f(x)dx=f(1), -1<a<1$ or $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }n\cdot \int_{0}^{1}x^{n}f(x^{n})dx=\int_{0}^{1}f(t)dt$ How to use them to solve my limits in the same way?

On other words, what are the similarities between these limits?